# how to do validation on only changed field in update api?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

how to do validation on only changed field which come as json on update api.

project use:
java+maven+hibernate+spring mvc

```
@Entity
@Component("user")
@Table(name="user")
@DynamicUpdate
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Range(min = 0, max = 1000000)
@Column(name="user_id")
private int UserId;

@Size(min = 6, max = 20)
@Column(name="password")
//@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="StringType")
private String password;

@Size(min=2, max=20)
@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Size(min=2, max=20)
@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@Size(min=2,max=20)
@Column(name="surname")
private String surName;

@Email
@Column(name="email_address")
private String EmailAddress;

@Size(min = 10, max = 10)
@Phone(message = "please enter valid phone number")
@Column(name="mobile_number")
private String mobileNumber;
}
```

and my update api as bellow:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@PostMapping(value = "/candidate")
public ResponseEntity addCandidate(@Valid @RequestBody Candidate candidate, BindingResult result) {
    Map<String, Object> errors = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        here save error in errors list.
        }
        errors.put("error", errorList);
        return new ResponseEntity(errors, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
    candidateService.addCandidate(candidate);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

due to the above logic, it will check all attributes which do not update actually. 
what are other methods to apply validation only on changed attributes?

more explanation:
I have three class

1. user
2. candidate
3. employee

here user class contains all common information of candidate and employee and in a forther password also contains for login.

now when first time signs up, I want to do validation only on email + password only, but here due to @valid annotation, it does validation on all the attribute.

Comment: `Candidate` is a child of `User` class, and in this controller method you want check only part of constraints inherited from `User` class, right?

Comment: see more explanation in question

Comment: Ok, what about  create dto class with necessary constraints? In common case work with entity in controller is bad idea. Better choice receive dto class with necessary constraints, and then map it to entity.

Comment: can I use @valid annotation inside repository class?